# how to fork then npm or yarn install a package that is a part of a monorepo from github

Tags: javascript, npm-install, yarnpkg, fusionjs

I'm trying to install a package from https://github.com/fusionjs/fusionjs .  It seems as if the package that I'd like to fork, modify, and install using npm install has been moved to the link I gave and I was wondering how i would go about forking and then installing the fork from github.  The package in question is `fusion-plugin-react-router`.  Thank you

Comment: You will need to make your modifications, and publish it to npm as your own package. Better yet, if you are fixing a bug or adding a feature, raise a pull request to the original repository so the open source community can benefit from it.

Comment: I suppose, I was interested in eventually submitting a pull request but was wondering how I can install it from github instead of using yarn install ../pathtofork locally or yarn/npm linking it.

Comment: sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but do you have a GitHub account? If you do, you just login GitHub and click the "Fork" button near the top-right from https://github.com/fushionjs/fushionjs. Then you can clone your fork and proceed from there. Not sure if that is what you're asking for.

Comment: @reactor You'd need to open that repo and understand how your package is built yourself. If you face issues you can ask specific queries here.